# ASP.NET nested control scrolling when focus is set

Tags: asp.net, scroll, setfocus

I have a nested control within a master page. When I explicitly set the focus on the first textbox on this control, the page shifts up to this first textbox. Is there a way to prevent the page from jumping up but still set the focus so the user doesn't have to click into the textbox? I want them to be able to start typing right when the page displays.

Comment: The control is visible. The structure is like this: An ascx user control is loaded into a master page aspx. Within the ascx lives a textbox which is visible. When the user navigates to this page, I want the cursor to be already in this textbox so they can start typing into it without clicking it first. Setting focus on this text box allows me to do this but the side effect is that when the page is loaded, the page moves up so that the textbox is just below the top of the browser which bumps the top of the page up and out of view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a browser setting, as it works automatic:

http://jsfiddle.net/KjCuM/

You could put a fix in place to then scroll back to the top of the page perhaps, but I think it makes sense for the control to be viewable on the screen if there is focus on it. Otherwise the user will not be able to see what they are submitting.

Comment: Curt - see my last comment. The control is visible and almost at the top of the page.